# Raspi4 missing PTC, 5V over-current and overvoltage protection?

Tags: raspberry-pi

From this source https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-3-model-b

This is power section of "Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+"

[image: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+]

compare to this power section of "Raspberry Pi 4 Model B"

[image: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B]

You see that it missing ideal diode and PTC resettable fuse in Pi 4.

The question is.

1. If PTC missing, how this circuit prevent over voltage?
2. Any engineering reason why we want to design it that way??

My initial guess are.

1. It think if Overvoltage happen, the zener diode will burn and there are no potection at all.
2. Maybe something to consider about USB C design? (some safty feature that not requir PTC)
3. PTC might cause problem?? by acting like resistor cause voltage to drop or ripple
4. PI just remove OVP feature?  (that sound terrify)

Comment: 2. Cost versus necessity.

Comment: Why would a standard USB device need overvoltage protection anyway? The D1 is not a zener but a TVS that can clamp tens of amps of surge current in overvoltage situations, and in case of standard USB devices, they would not be able to give out tens of amps at overvoltage to begin with. 2A PTC sounds very small as for example USB HDDs could take 1A when running so in that case the PTC could already trigger, maybe they found it causes more problems than what it solves and left it out. Only the designers of Raspberry Pi can answer this question, we can only guess why they did what they did.

Answer (score 1):

1. the PTC is for over current.
2. Could be a zillion reasons - you'd have to ask the person who designed it. It could be due to cost, space or they may have found in the Pi3 design the PTC didn't save the board from stupidity.

On the Pi3, if overvoltage happened, what was the outcome? PTCs (polyfuses) are notoriously slow to react, very temperature sensitive and have a habit of going up in flames. You might find on the Pi3, overvoltage might smoke the 'perfect diode' and/or the transzorb.

Comment: I think PTC is necessary to perform OVP along side with zener diode.